# How to plot smooth line through four points in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame include two groups, each group with four points, and I want to plot them using smooth line in r.
The dataframe is:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(12,25,50,85,12,25,50,85), y=c(1.02, 1.05, 0.99, 1.07, 1.03, 1.06, 1.09, 1.10), Type=c("AD","AD","AD","AD","WT","WT","WT","WT"))
```

I used the code:

```
ggplot(df) + 
geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=Type, group=Type), size = 3) + 
geom_line(aes(y=y, x=x, group = Type, color=Type)) + 
stat_smooth(aes(y=y, x=x), method = "loose", formula = y~ poly(x, 21), se = FALSE)
```

However the plot I got is not smooth as I expected.
How could I change on code?
Is it because the limited point number?
Thanks a lot in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems with your code. Firstly, there is no method called `"loose"` for regression (did you mis-spell `"loess"`?). Secondly, if you want a polynomial regression you probably want `method = lm`. Thirdly, if you have four points in each series, you can have at most a degree-3 polynomial.

Using `lm` with `y ~ poly(x, 3)` works quite well here:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = Type)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) + 
  stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ poly(x, 3), se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Or even just a loess with `y ~ x`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=Type)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) + 
  stat_smooth(method = loess, formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That is what I want. I noticed the parameter for poly is 3. Is it a fix set calculated by point number minus 1?

Comment: @Cynthia yes, in general, if you want a perfect fit to _n_ points then you need an _n-1_ degree polynomial. Of course, it might be that by chance you need a lower degree (for example if your points are all in a straight line then a degree-1 polynomial will fit)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know how to specific set color for these two groups? In this plot, colors are red and green by default. If I want to change to red and blue, how to give a pre-set color library?

Comment: You can add `+ scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))`, or whichever colors you want.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an alternative way of doing it.

```
  geom_point(size = 3) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 0.75, se = FALSE)
```

You can the `span`-parameter. See some examples below:

`span == 1`:

[image]

`span == 0.75`:

[image]